# PHP internal array pointer issue with variable passed by reference in recursive function with foreach

Tags: php, performance, recursion, foreach, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to build a hierarchical associative array with parent-child relationships. The input data comes in as an array of elements. Each element has an id and a parent-id.

For efficiency, when an element finds its parent I want to remove that child element from source data so cycles aren't wasted checking if that element is a child of other elements.

Here is the code:

```
// parentid == 0 indicates a root node
function buildTree(&$elements, $parentid=0){
    $branch = array();

    foreach($elements as $key => $element){
        if($element['parentid'] == $parentid){
            $twig = $element;
            unset($elements[$key]);
            $twig['children'] = buildTree($elements, $element['pageid']);
            $branch[] = $twig;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that in certain cases the some elements never find their parent.

I think this is happening because the `$elements` variable is being passed by reference and deeper levels of recursion are corrupting the position of the internal array pointer for the outer level, causing other children to be skipped over and not touched in the outer level's foreach loop.

I've tried to see if there's a way to save the position of the internal array pointer before going in another level of recursion, and then restoring the position when the function returns, but it does not appear that this is possible in PHP.

If I take the `&` out to not pass the `$elements` variable by reference, then the function works perfectly. Unfortunately this leaves elements to be processed by the foreach even if they've already been saved under their proper parent, wasting a bit of processing time.

Any ideas about how I could remove child elements from the unsorted pool of elements after they've been assigned to their parent?

**Edit:** Of course some sample data would help:

```
$source_data = unserialize('a:33:{i:0;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"53";s:3:"key";s:2:"53";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"52";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:8:"Example 2.0";}i:1;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"68";s:3:"key";s:2:"68";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"53";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:5:"Audit";}i:2;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"65";s:3:"key";s:2:"65";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"25";s:7:"tooltip";s:26:"CastIron Deployment Helper";s:5:"title";s:8:"helper";}i:3;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"50";s:3:"key";s:2:"50";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"49";s:7:"tooltip";s:17:"Calendar Template";s:5:"title";s:8:"Calendar";}i:4;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"28";s:3:"key";s:2:"28";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"27";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:15:"querty Gifts";}i:5;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"24";s:3:"key";s:2:"24";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:4:"More_Samples";}i:6;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"35";s:3:"key";s:2:"35";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:38:"Ideas for features of this wiki webapp";s:5:"title";s:6:"Design";}i:7;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"70";s:3:"key";s:2:"70";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"25";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:26:"Environments & Credentials";}i:8;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"67";s:3:"key";s:2:"67";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"36";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:19:"Helping Downstreams";}i:9;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:1:"1";s:3:"key";s:1:"1";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:4:"Home";}i:10;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"64";s:3:"key";s:2:"64";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"53";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:5:"ITC02";}i:11;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"27";s:3:"key";s:2:"27";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:14:"More_Samples topics";}i:12;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"26";s:3:"key";s:2:"26";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"25";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:2:"MQ";}i:13;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"55";s:3:"key";s:2:"55";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"36";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:5:"Music";}i:14;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"73";s:3:"key";s:2:"73";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"52";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:5:"Other";}i:15;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"29";s:3:"key";s:2:"29";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"1";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:3:"Sample";}i:16;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"34";s:3:"key";s:2:"34";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"29";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:14:"Sample 2013 Goals";}i:17;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"33";s:3:"key";s:2:"33";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"29";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:8:"Sample 2014";}i:18;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"31";s:3:"key";s:2:"31";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"29";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:6:"Sample R2";}i:19;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"32";s:3:"key";s:2:"32";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"29";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:13:"Sample Text Only";}i:20;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"25";s:3:"key";s:2:"25";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:9:"Reference";}i:21;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"62";s:3:"key";s:2:"62";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"52";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:8:"S&D reps";}i:22;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"36";s:3:"key";s:2:"36";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:7:"Sandbox";}i:23;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"71";s:3:"key";s:2:"71";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"52";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:9:"Schedules";}i:24;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"72";s:3:"key";s:2:"72";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"52";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:9:"Schedules";}i:25;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"51";s:3:"key";s:2:"51";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:13:"Special Pages";}i:26;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"63";s:3:"key";s:2:"63";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"35";s:7:"tooltip";s:36:"How to handle tasks and task parsing";s:5:"title";s:5:"Tasks";}i:27;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"49";s:3:"key";s:2:"49";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:47:"Template pages for use when creating new pages.";s:5:"title";s:9:"Templates";}i:28;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"52";s:3:"key";s:2:"52";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:4:"Work";}i:29;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"14";s:3:"key";s:2:"14";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"1";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:8:"another!";}i:30;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"54";s:3:"key";s:2:"54";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"25";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:4:"tmux";}i:31;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"12";s:3:"key";s:2:"12";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"1";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:5:"what?";}i:32;a:5:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"13";s:3:"key";s:2:"13";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"1";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:5:"zippy";}}');
$correct_result = unserialize('a:9:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"24";s:3:"key";s:2:"24";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:4:"More_Samples";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=24";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:1;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"35";s:3:"key";s:2:"35";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:38:"Ideas for features of this wiki webapp";s:5:"title";s:6:"Design";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=35";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"63";s:3:"key";s:2:"63";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"35";s:7:"tooltip";s:36:"How to handle tasks and task parsing";s:5:"title";s:5:"Tasks";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=63";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}}}i:2;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:1:"1";s:3:"key";s:1:"1";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:4:"Home";s:4:"href";s:7:"?page=1";s:8:"children";a:4:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"29";s:3:"key";s:2:"29";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"1";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:3:"Sample";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=29";s:8:"children";a:4:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"34";s:3:"key";s:2:"34";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"29";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:14:"Sample 2013 Goals";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=34";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:1;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"33";s:3:"key";s:2:"33";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"29";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:8:"Sample 2014";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=33";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:2;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"31";s:3:"key";s:2:"31";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"29";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:6:"Sample R2";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=31";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:3;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"32";s:3:"key";s:2:"32";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"29";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:13:"Sample Text Only";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=32";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}}}i:1;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"14";s:3:"key";s:2:"14";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"1";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:8:"another!";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=14";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:2;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"12";s:3:"key";s:2:"12";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"1";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:5:"what?";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=12";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:3;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"13";s:3:"key";s:2:"13";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"1";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:5:"zippy";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=13";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}}}i:3;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"27";s:3:"key";s:2:"27";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:14:"More_Samples topics";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=27";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"28";s:3:"key";s:2:"28";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"27";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:15:"querty Gifts";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=28";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}}}i:4;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"25";s:3:"key";s:2:"25";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:9:"Reference";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=25";s:8:"children";a:4:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"65";s:3:"key";s:2:"65";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"25";s:7:"tooltip";s:26:"CastIron Deployment Helper";s:5:"title";s:8:"helper";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=65";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:1;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"70";s:3:"key";s:2:"70";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"25";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:26:"Environments & Credentials";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=70";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:2;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"26";s:3:"key";s:2:"26";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"25";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:2:"MQ";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=26";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:3;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"54";s:3:"key";s:2:"54";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"25";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:4:"tmux";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=54";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}}}i:5;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"36";s:3:"key";s:2:"36";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:7:"Sandbox";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=36";s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"67";s:3:"key";s:2:"67";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"36";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:19:"Helping Downstreams";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=67";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:1;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"55";s:3:"key";s:2:"55";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"36";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:5:"Music";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=55";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}}}i:6;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"51";s:3:"key";s:2:"51";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:13:"Special Pages";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=51";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:7;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"49";s:3:"key";s:2:"49";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:47:"Template pages for use when creating new pages.";s:5:"title";s:9:"Templates";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=49";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"50";s:3:"key";s:2:"50";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"49";s:7:"tooltip";s:17:"Calendar Template";s:5:"title";s:8:"Calendar";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=50";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}}}i:8;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"52";s:3:"key";s:2:"52";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:4:"Work";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=52";s:8:"children";a:5:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"53";s:3:"key";s:2:"53";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"52";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:8:"Example 2.0";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=53";s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"68";s:3:"key";s:2:"68";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"53";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:5:"Audit";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=68";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:1;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"64";s:3:"key";s:2:"64";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"53";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:5:"ITC02";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=64";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}}}i:1;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"73";s:3:"key";s:2:"73";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"52";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:5:"Other";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=73";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:2;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"62";s:3:"key";s:2:"62";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"52";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:8:"S&D reps";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=62";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:3;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"71";s:3:"key";s:2:"71";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"52";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:9:"Schedules";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=71";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:4;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"72";s:3:"key";s:2:"72";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"52";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:9:"Schedules";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=72";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}}}}';
$by_reference = unserialize('a:9:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"24";s:3:"key";s:2:"24";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:4:"More_Samples";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=24";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:1;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"35";s:3:"key";s:2:"35";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:38:"Ideas for features of this wiki webapp";s:5:"title";s:6:"Design";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=35";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"63";s:3:"key";s:2:"63";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"35";s:7:"tooltip";s:36:"How to handle tasks and task parsing";s:5:"title";s:5:"Tasks";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=63";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}}}i:2;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:1:"1";s:3:"key";s:1:"1";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:4:"Home";s:4:"href";s:7:"?page=1";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"29";s:3:"key";s:2:"29";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"1";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:3:"Sample";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=29";s:8:"children";a:4:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"34";s:3:"key";s:2:"34";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"29";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:14:"Sample 2013 Goals";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=34";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:1;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"33";s:3:"key";s:2:"33";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"29";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:8:"Sample 2014";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=33";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:2;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"31";s:3:"key";s:2:"31";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"29";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:6:"Sample R2";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=31";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:3;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"32";s:3:"key";s:2:"32";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"29";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:13:"Sample Text Only";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=32";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}}}}}i:3;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"27";s:3:"key";s:2:"27";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:14:"More_Samples topics";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=27";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"28";s:3:"key";s:2:"28";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"27";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:15:"querty Gifts";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=28";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}}}i:4;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"25";s:3:"key";s:2:"25";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:9:"Reference";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=25";s:8:"children";a:4:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"65";s:3:"key";s:2:"65";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"25";s:7:"tooltip";s:26:"CastIron Deployment Helper";s:5:"title";s:8:"helper";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=65";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:1;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"70";s:3:"key";s:2:"70";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"25";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:26:"Environments & Credentials";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=70";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:2;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"26";s:3:"key";s:2:"26";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"25";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:2:"MQ";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=26";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:3;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"54";s:3:"key";s:2:"54";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"25";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:4:"tmux";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=54";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}}}i:5;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"36";s:3:"key";s:2:"36";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:7:"Sandbox";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=36";s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"67";s:3:"key";s:2:"67";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"36";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:19:"Helping Downstreams";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=67";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:1;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"55";s:3:"key";s:2:"55";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"36";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:5:"Music";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=55";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}}}i:6;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"51";s:3:"key";s:2:"51";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:13:"Special Pages";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=51";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:7;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"49";s:3:"key";s:2:"49";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:47:"Template pages for use when creating new pages.";s:5:"title";s:9:"Templates";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=49";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"50";s:3:"key";s:2:"50";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"49";s:7:"tooltip";s:17:"Calendar Template";s:5:"title";s:8:"Calendar";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=50";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}}}i:8;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"52";s:3:"key";s:2:"52";s:8:"parentid";s:1:"0";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:4:"Work";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=52";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"53";s:3:"key";s:2:"53";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"52";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:8:"Example 2.0";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=53";s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"68";s:3:"key";s:2:"68";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"53";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:5:"Audit";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=68";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}i:1;a:7:{s:6:"pageid";s:2:"64";s:3:"key";s:2:"64";s:8:"parentid";s:2:"53";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:5:"ITC02";s:4:"href";s:8:"?page=64";s:8:"children";a:0:{}}}}}}}';
```

`$source_data` is the unsorted source data, `$correct_result` is what I get when I don't pass `$elements` by reference (this is what I want), and `$by_reference` is what I get when I pass `&$elements` by reference (incorrect result).

Comment: I think you should provide some data in PHP format and show some result example and what's wrong with it.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek good idea, just added the sample data I'm experiencing the problem with.

Answer (score 0):

Ithing you have to reindex the $elements array after unset try this ..

```
unset($elements[$key]);
$temp_array=array_values($elements);
$twig['children'] = buildTree($temp_array, $element['id']);
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, reindexing the array inside of a foreach() is going to cause an error

Comment: @CJWurtz I have not tested.... storing the array_values($elements) to another variable may not generate an issue...